# Ejecutar linea de comando linux desde python indicando directorio de output

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, imagemagick

Quiero ejecutar desde un `script Python` unas lineas de comando de `linux`, que convierte las hojas de un `.pdf` a `.jpg`. Pero quiero indicarle el `directorio` en el que voy a guardar los `.jpgs`. Y mi problema surge que solo me transforma los `.pdfs`, pero los aloja en mismo directorio donde se ubican los `.pdf`. Hay alguna palabra que debo agregarle a la linea de comando?,

La linea limpia es:

```
convert nombre_pdf.pdf  nombre_pdf.jpg
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import os

#posicionarme en el directorio Descargas
os.chdir('Descargas')
#obtener todos los archivos del directorio actual (Descargas)
dir_list = os.listdir()
#iterar todos los elementos
for item_list in dir_list:
    #split nombre y extension
    nombre_base, extension = os.path.splitext(item_list)
    #
    if extension == '.pdf': 
        #Solo se convierten los que tienen extensión .pdf
        cmd_str = ' '.join([f"convert '{item_list}' '{nombre_base}.png'"])
        #Imprimir comando a ejecutar.
        print(cmd_str)
        #Ejecución de comando.
        os.system(cmd_str)
```

pd: espero que no se molesten por no usar `subprocess`.

Estoy usando `ubuntu`

Comment: El directorio donde quieres los png ¿sería uno predefinido en el código (cuál)? ¿O sería un parámetro que se reciba por línea de comandos (es decir, a través de `sys.argv`)?

Comment: Si. sería predefinido,  dentro de `Descargas`.  osea en  `Descargas/images`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es una ruta predefinida como dices, bastaría concatenar esa ruta delante del nombre de fichero de salida, por ejemplo `" ... 'images/{nombre_base}.png'"`

Sin embargo aprovecho para reescribir tu código haciendo uso de la biblioteca `pathlib`, que es la forma moderna (Python 3.4+) y preferible de trabajar con rutas y nombres de fichero. Esta biblioteca te proporciona funciones de utilidad como `glob()` para especificar mediante "comodines" nombres de fichero con una extensión común, y métodos sobre cada elemento resultante que te permiten cambiar su extensión de forma sencilla, o concatenarles nombres de ruta mediante el operador `/`. Las rutas resultantes además son convertidas por Python si es necesario para que sean válidas según tu operativo (por ejemplo, en Windows cambiaria las `/` por `\`).

Haciendo uso de esta librería lo que buscas se haría así:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

d_in = Path('Descargas')
d_out = Path('Descargas/images')

for pdf in d_in.glob("*.pdf"):
    out = d_out / pdf.with_suffix(".png")
    cmd_str = f"convert '{pdf}' '{out}'"
    print(cmd_str)
    os.system(cmd_str)
```

(Nota: no uso `chdir()`, por lo que el comando `convert` especifica tanto la carpeta donde están los pdf como la carpeta donde han de ir los png)

Este *script* deberá ejecutarse mientras estás en tu "home". Podría hacerse más genérico si usas por ejemplo `d_in = Path.home() / "Descargas"`  y `d_out = d_in / "images"`. De este modo las rutas que se pasarían al comando `convert` serían absolutas y no dependerían de en qué carpeta estás cuando ejecutas el script.

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia , no sabia lo de `convert` con la dirección. el `script` lo tengo en varios subdirectorios desde `home`. asi se complica usar  `Path.home()/"Descargas" `. lo usaré con `os.getcwd()`. De nuevo gracias, funciona como quería.

Comment: También puedes usar `Path(".")` para obtener la carpeta actual (o `Path(".").resolve()` si quieres convertir la ruta relativa en absoluta) y así no depender de las funciones de rutas de `os`.

Comment: excelente, otra vez gracias.